# Init block VS init() private method called in constructor

Tags: java, initialization

I know there are several ways to initialize stuff at instance creation in Java, but I'm interested in the difference between the following 2 possibilities.

Case 1:

```
{
    // common init code for all constructors
}

public MyType() {
    super();
    // specific init code
}

public MyType(Object arg) {
    super(arg);
    // specific init code
}
```

Case 2:

```
public MyType() {
    super();
    init();
    // specific init code
}

public MyType(Object arg) {
    super(arg);
    init();
    // specific init code
}

private void init() {
    // common init code for all constructors
}
```

I believe these 2 cases are equivalent in terms of code. I think the first is faster because there is 1 less method call, but on the other hand it might be confusing for someone who is not very knowledgeable about initialization.

Is there another difference that I have missed that could lead us to choose one over the other? **Which option should I use preferably?**

*Note: the* `init()` *method is private, and I know a different visibility could lead to initialization bugs (when subclassing), this is not the point.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe the first is faster because there is 1 less method call, but I think it is less readable.

I wouldn't even consider efficiency here as it would make just a minor difference of method call. But why do you think it is less readable? It's a well known feature of Java language.

> Which option should I use preferably?

The benefit of first approach is, you've to write less code. And there is slight chance of human error in second approach. Generally you would use instance initializer block when you want the initialization to be done in every constructor. That saves you from explicitly writing same code in all constructor. With the other approach, you have to remember to invoke `init()` method from all the constructors.

But if you want some initialization to be part of some constructor, then the second approach might be useful. But that is very rare IMO.

Comment: I find it perfectly readable, but I've met many Java programmers who don't know about this non-static init block, that's why I said this.

Comment: @Joffrey Well in that case, they would learn something that they don't know, and should know.

Answer (score 0):

In short, init code in first case will be called before constructor, in second - after.
Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335311/static-initializer-in-java).

General rule is to avoid constructions like theese and use [static-factory-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617311/creation-of-objects-constructors-or-static-factory-methods) instead.

Order might matter then calling this() instead of super():
Consider code:

```
public class InitOrderTest {
static class Super {
    Super() {
        System.out.println("Super constructor");
    }
}
static class Puper extends Super {
    {
        System.out.println("Code block");
    }
    Puper() {
        this("Self constructor");
        init();
    }

    public Puper(String inner) {
        System.out.println(inner);
    }

    private void init() {
        System.out.println("Init call");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Puper();
}
```

}

It prints:

```
Super constructor
Code block
Self constructor
Init call
```

Comment: *init code in first case will be called before constructor, in second - after* well that depends on where you call `init()`. But the init block is not really called before, it is called right after the `super()` call.

Comment: *init code in first case will be called before constructor* - No this is not the case. The functionality of two codes would be exactly equivalent.

Comment: @theme Anyway, thanks for pointing out static factory methods.