# Simple Object vs. Factory vs. Constructor - Practical Example

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, factory

There are three ways of creating objects in JavaScript:

1. by simple Object creating
2. by Factory function
3. by Constructor function

---

1. Simple Object Creation:

   ```
   var ronaldo = {
       name: "Ronaldo",
       age: "35",
       quote: "Hi I am Ronaldo", 
       salary: function(x){ return x+2500; }
   };
   ```
2. Factory Function:

   ```
   function human(x,y,z,i){
       return{
           name: x,
           age: y,
           quote: z,
           salary: function(i){ return i+2500; }
       }
   };
   var Zini = human('Zenidan','41','I am Zidane',7500);
   ```
3. Constructor Function:

   ```
   var human = function(x,y,z,i){
       this.name = x,
       this.age = y,
       this.quote = z, 
       this.salary = function(i){ return i+2500; }
   };
   var Lampd = new human('Frank Lampard','39','I am Frank J Lampard',5500);
   ```

Can someone provide simple illustrations of when to use which of these methods to create objects in simple terms, so that a naive can also understand?

I went through the following links, but it’s a bit complicated to understand:

- [Constructors vs Factory Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods)
- [Constructor function vs Factory functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698726/constructor-function-vs-factory-functions)
- [Creation of Objects: Constructors or Static Factory Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617311/creation-of-objects-constructors-or-static-factory-methods)

So I’m asking for some simple practical cases.

Comment: i am also want to see practical cases for above mention question ☻

Comment: There are more ways to create objects in JS, `new`-keyword and `Object.create()`

Comment: Can you provide simple 'code snippents' for those. It would be helpful. Also, no answer so far. ;(

Comment: You're basically asking for "how, when, and why do I use various JS OOP methods". IMO this is too broad, and extensively covered by tutorials, books, and previous SO questions.

Comment: What is the difference between a Factory and a function constructor?

Comment: the style convention for JavaScript is to capitalize constructor function names and use lowercase names for instance variables.  http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: @VanderVidi A factory constructs objects based on arbitrary criteria given to the factory. A function constructor is just that, a function constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Use simple objects for data: when all you need is a bundle of key/value pairs.

In your example of a simple object, you have more than just data: the `salary` method adds behavior to the object. If you're going to end up with many objects like that, it's better for performance and maintainability to have just one `salary` method that is shared between all of the objects, rather than each object having its own `salary` method. A way to share a method among many objects is to put the method on a prototype of the objects.

You can use a constructor function when you need to create an object that is an instance of a prototype. This is a good place to read about that, but it's a little dense: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

The MDN link above also demonstrates ECMAScript 2015 `class` syntax, which is an alternative to constructor functions.

> Update: See Dave Newton's comment for a good example of when to use a factory

Comment: Factories are useful under the same circumstances as other OOP languages, e.g., if you're consuming JSON data and you need data/behavior based on some form of marker (pretend this is JSON): `{ id: n, type: 'some_type', data: { whatever } }`. If you have multiple types you'd need a factory to generate behavioral objects from them, for example, a type might have its own editor implementation.

Comment: Also, when you don't need `this`, I'd recommend using a regular function or static method instead of an instance method http://stackoverflow.com/a/29291666/2482570. To me, making a function an instance method signals that you intend to use `this`. In your example, `const salary = x => x + 2500` would be a fine way to write the function.